# Laravel + Digital Ocean + Serverpilot = Domain routing

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, digital-ocean

i have server from Digital Ocean. I  use Serverpilot. How do i domain routing using by laravel 5.3 ?

Rweb example :

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'admin.developer.app'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () { return view('dash') });
});

Route::group(['domain' => 'department.developer.app'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () { return view('dash') });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need access to DNS zonefile settings at your DNS provider.

- Set up a catchall DNS entry (an `A` record for `*` pointing to your server address)
- Your `.htaccess` file must be set up correctly that it catches all subdomains and renders `developer.app` for your routing to work correctly. (I think the default laravel `.htaccess` is fine)
- Add `ServerAlias *.developer.app` to your VirtualHost config and restart the webserver

Comment: Thanks for answer.

DNS Records ; http://prntscr.com/djc6tv

.htaccess File ; http://prntscr.com/djc77n

Comment: Both looks fine, it should work now. In your VirtualHosts config, make sure that your webserver listens for the requests on all subdomains. After that, restart your webserver.

Comment: @MuratGüven Take a look at ServerPilot's documentation to see [how to use wildcard subdomains](https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-use-wildcard-subdomains.html). ServerPilot will take care of the server configuration. There are no Nginx or Apache files you need to modify.

Comment: @MuratGüven any error message in your webserver log? (Default locations are `/var/log/apache2/error.log` or `/var/log/nginx/logs/error.log`)